# Statsmodels power analysis number of observations

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels, power-analysis

I'm confused with statsmodels API of the [TTestIndPower](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.power.TTestIndPower.html#statsmodels.stats.power.TTestIndPower) class.

In the `plot_power` function the number of observations plotted are the total number of samples or the number of samples of each group?

Comment: From the comment they have "If the second argument is nobs1, then the number of observations in the plot are those for the first sample." I would assume it's the total number of samples but this would go against the other functions of the class, power and solve_power

Answer (score 0):

It's per group.

This is the power_plot I generated with statsmodels

```
from statsmodels.stats.power import TTestIndPower

panalysis = TTestIndPower()

panalysis.plot_power(
    dep_var="nobs",
    nobs=np.arange(5, 101),
    effect_size=np.arange(0.5, 1.5, .2),
    alpha=0.01,
    ax=ax,
)
```

[image]

And this is the confirmation with R for an effect size (es) of 0.7

```
> library(pwr)
> pwr.t.test(power = 0.8, sig.level = 0.01, d = 0.7)

 Two-sample t test power calculation 

          n = 49.35336
          d = 0.7
  sig.level = 0.01
      power = 0.8
  alternative = two.sided

 NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

Comment: Can you explain, why you set `ax=ax` ? Did you forget to declare it here?

Comment: forgot to declare it. I usually declare the ax like this: `_, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(2, 1.5), dpi=600)`